# How can I use existing Activerecord model in rails in ruby script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I have a ruby script at the root directory of rails application and I need to access existing Activerecord model which is created inside rails environment. How can I use something like

```
user = User.new
```

in my script without establishing a new connection or create a new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two common ways to deal with Rails models from the command line:

**1) rake tasks**

Create a rake task in `lib/tasks`

```
# example lib/tasks/foo.rake
desc 'an example task'
task :foo => [:environment] do  
  user = User.new
  ...
end
```

And call that task from your command line with:

```
rake foo
```

**2) script runner**

Create a method within your application that does the job

```
# example in app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def self.foo
    user = User.new
    ...
  end
end
```

And call this method from the command line with:

```
rails runner "User.foo"
```

I prefer the second way, because it is easier to test and reuse the code.

Comment: did you forget the "def" keyword?